Why does $ρgh$ not cancel?
Consider a section of a cone placed upside down of length h (image attached). The cross sectional areas are shown. If water falls into the broader cross sectional area with velocity u, for A1

Pressure energy at A1 is P0 (atmospheric pressure)

Potential energy is ρgh since it's at a height h above the origin.

Kinetic energy is ½ρu²


For A2:

Pressure energy here is P0 + ρgh ( the ρgh is due to the height of the fluid column above it)

Potential energy is 0.

Assuming that the velocity at this point is v, Kinetic energy here is ½ρv²


Using bernoulli's equation :
$$½ρu² + P0 + ρgh = P0 + ρgh + 0 + ½ρv²$$
And we get  u = v which is not true since the cross sectional areas are different so that leads to a contradiction...?
Can somebody please explain where I'm going wrong? (When I saw an explanation of the same, the guy only considered ρgh  due to potential energy on the left hand side. He did not consider ρgh on the right hand side due to the fluid column)


How about a link to the video so we can see what the “guy” is saying in context

The problem in the video is completely different. The two “points” under consideration are outside the pipe. The pipe has a uniform diameter. The answer just posted by John Rennie is the correct explanation

You have assumed that the pressure at the base is $P_0 + \rho g h$ but this assumption is not true.
If the fluid was not moving then your assumption would be correct, but in this case not only is the fluid moving but it is flowing faster at the bottom than at the top because $v = u \times A_1/A_2$. The energy for this increase of speed came from the pressure doing work on the fluid, and as a result the pressure decreased.
The correct way to analyse this is to note that (assuming the fluid is incompressible) the rate of mass transport must be constant i.e. $vA_2 = uA_1$, and that's how we get the expression for $v$ that I wrote above. Then knowing $v$ we can use the Bernoulli equation to find the pressure at the base.
